# VPN Chain - Multiple VPN's in One Connection

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

How to go with multiple VPN's in one chain?

I need to go trough 3 different VPN's

```
vpn[0].conf
vpn[1].conf
vpn[2].conf
```

I know I can go

```
openvpn --config vpn[0].conf
```

But I certainly don't know how to chain them.

Any advice? I just need VPN to connect to VPN where there's my server with also VPN that can access company's VPN. Also on that second VPN I would like to have ssh access !important in that network.

Comment: Do you mean you want to connect to the first VPN in order to be able to establish the second VPN in order to be able to establish the third VPN?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main steps that involve quite a few single steps. You need administrative access to all VPN server except the last because you probably to setup  NAT and firewall rules.

The first VPN should be fairly simple.

For the second VPN you would need NAT on the VPN server of the first VPN. Try first to establish a working connection for PING  to the server of the second VPN through the first VPN and if that works, expand on this to get the second VPN working.

For the third VPN you need NAT on the server of the second VPN. Again try to establish a working connection with PING and if that works, expand on this to get the third VPN working.